# Changing the postmapping in Spring gives me a 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Right now, I have I can send post requests to /message using Postman according to this

```java
@RestController
@Api // For swagger document
public class MessageController {

    private final MessageService messageService;

    public MessageController(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "POST a message")
    @PostMapping(value = "/message", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity createMessage(@Valid @RequestBody MessageVo messageVo,
        @RequestParam(value = "callingApplication") String callingApplication) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        String id = messageService.createMessage(messageVo, callingApplication);
        response.put("id", id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

If I change the `@PostMapping(value = "/message")` to `@PostMapping(value = "/message2")` for example, I am getting a 404 instead of a 200 (while also changing the URL to a 2 at the end). Is there somewhere else the mapping is defined?

Edit: I might add that I'm using "mvn clean package" to compile with Jooq as I'm also running a Postgres database locally. It might be that when I press the build button to compile on Intellij locally, it's not compiling the whole thing.

Comment: Did you do `/message/2` in postman?

Comment: @dan1st no. /message2?callingApplication=abc

Answer (score 0):

If @PostMapping(value = "/message2") then URL to hit in postman should be -

base_url/message2?callingApplication=abc

The 'callingApplication' is a mandatory query parameter.

Comment: Yes, I've added the query paramater. I still get the 404

Answer (score 0):

Realized I had to compile with `mvn clean package`, not from ide